# Android GeoCoder returns only 1 result

Tags: android, geolocation, location, google-geocoder

In my Android application, the user can enter an address to set up his location. For that, I'm using Geocoder and the getFromLocationName method.

Everything works fine when I'm looking for basic cities but as soon as I look for ambiguous location, such as Villefranche in France (there are more than 10 cities called Villefranche in France), GeoCoder returns only 1 result.

Here is how I call the method:

```
resultReverseGeo = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(name, 5);
Log.d(TAG, "Size " + resultReverseGeo.size()); // size is always = 1
```

Any idea?

Comment: I tried with "street" and it does return several addresses. I still don't know why it returns only 1 address with "villefranche" or other amiguous city but thanks!

Comment: I tried with "street" and ambiguous cities and get always 1. when i put them in web google maps i get all the options.

Comment: Facing the same problem.
For example, Paris gives only one result.

Comment: Having same problem. But I think we have an answer here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272825/google-maps-geocoder-api-returns-only-1-result-for-starbucks